# How to have context menu and reordering cells in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, contextmenu

I have a `UICollectionViewController`, and the items need to have an iOS 13 context menu.
At the same time, the user needs to be able to reorder items.

By default, the context menu is opened after a long tap on the item. However, the same gesture (different recognizer) enables reordering mode. I'd like to have it like we can reorder apps on the home screen: Long tap shows the context menu, and an even longer tap then closes that context menu and enables wiggle mode.

I know that it is possible to provide my own gesture recognizer to begin reordering items. So I could install a recognizer with a duration of 2 seconds, knowing the context menu opens after 1 second.
But I could not find a way how to close the context menu programmatically. If I tap next to it to close it, the reordering mode is cancelled, too.

Do you have any suggestions how to adequately combine reordering items and context menus?

Comment: I would also love to know the answer.